# E-commerce Tracking Orders Dates Mismatch Issue Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am facing a big issue with google analytics, its not showing up orders with correct date. A user on website placed order on **20-July-2018** but its showing up under **22-July-2018**. As I checked my code 2-3 times and its having proper conditions to submit the reports only once for a order but really don't know whats wrong with API implementations. Can anyone have idea about this ?

**Javascript Code :-**

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-1179*****', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

**PHP Code :-**

```
/* applied check to call this only once for a order */    
    echo "<script> ga('require', 'ecommerce');";                            
    echo "ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
      'id': '{$trans['id']}',
      'affiliation': '{$trans['affiliation']}',
      'revenue': '{$trans['revenue']}',
      'shipping': '{$trans['shipping']}',
      'tax': '{$trans['tax']}'
    });";

    //echo $this->getTransactionJs($trans);
    foreach ($items as &$item) {
          echo "ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
          'id': '{$trans['id']}',
          'name': '{$item['name']}',
          'sku': '{$item['sku']}',
          'category': '{$item['category']}',
          'price': '{$item['price']}',
          'quantity': '{$item['quantity']}'
        });";
    }
    echo "ga('ecommerce:send');</script>";
```

Comment: When you check the pageviews, that are generated on this same success page, do they show up on the correct date, or do you see similar differences? It might give you an idea, whether this is ecommerce specific, or general to your Analytics implementation.

Comment: date format timezone is same on website and google analytics. I already checked that.

Comment: how do you know it is the same user and not a different user? using user id?

Comment: I unable to understand what you are asking. Please explain.